# Problems with NodeJS authentication Json Web Token and Nginx

Tags: node.js, nginx, jwt

I'm having trouble authenticating a user in my NodeJS / React application, I know that the question is not very much related to programming, but someone can help me. Come on the question.

I created a work schedule management application for the company's employees, the API I made in Node JS and the Front with React. As employees are in Rio and São Paulo, they would have to have access via the web. So we set up a server with a fixed IP for the access of Rio people. We installed Ubuntu 20.04 with Nginx, NodeJs and MongoDB.

So far so good, I installed the application and on the server and it works perfectly, but when accessed by another machine, inside and outside the network, there is an authentication error.

I've looked for how to pass the header and I've read a lot of articles to try to configure Nginx to accept this header that is passed by the Json Web Token.

In the application I pass a Header that I called x-auth-token, which I can check on the browser when I'm on the server, but I can't find this Header when I'm on another machine on the network or outside it. So I believe that is why the authentication error, I just don't know how to solve this.

I created this location in Nginx so that when they enter the server, run the application right away.

I changed this code a little and I will update it here too

```
 location / {
   proxy_pass https://xxx.xxx.x.xxx:3000;
   proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
   proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
   proxy_pass_header X-Auth-Token;
}
```

The xxx is not to put the external IP of the server.

Comment: I don't think `add_header 'x-auth-token' always;` is correct. From the docs `Syntax: add_header name value [always];` Also i don't think it serves the purpose you think. It's for adding new headers not to allow them to pass through proxy.. I would try `proxy_pass_header X-Auth-Token` instead. Also make sure you haven't set `proxy_pass_request_headers off;` as this would disable passing request headers to the node app. Also by default all the headers from request should be passed thtrough.

Comment: Thanks Molda, I will try to pass the proxy_pass_header and put off the request_headers 
and then I say if it worked

Comment: @Molda nop, I made the changes and still giving the same error. CONNECTION REFUSED 
why don't you pass jwt response.